# xargs and cp: find-style "{}+" multiple expansion?

Tags: unix, solaris, cp, xargs

I'd like to copy a group of files to destination folder.  But without needing to spawn a new instance of `cp` for each operation.

The arg format for `cp` seems to be:

```
cp src_file1 src_file2 src_file3 dest_dir/
```

Assuming I have a file with source file names listed line-by-line, how can this be done?

Since I have a very large number of files, the idea from @Scott below will not work, since it will hit the maximum command line length.

I'd like to somehow pipe that file of file names to `cp` and let it do it's thing.  `xargs` also can't seem to help, as it wants to tack on the expansion at the end of the command line.

Can this be done?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If `filelist` contains

```
apple
orange
banana
```

where those are the names of files that you want to copy to the `fruity` directory, type

```
cp `cat filelist` fruity
```

You don’t need the `/` at the end.

Warning: this won’t work if any of the file names contain spaces, e.g., `passion fruit`.

Comment: Won't quite work.. I've clarified the question.  There are _many_ files.

Comment: As long as none of the filenames contains a space or quote character, `xargs -J {} cp {} fruit < filelist` should work.  If there are spaces and/or quotes, you could go with [eicto’s answer](http://superuser.com/a/503571), or just do `tr "\n" "\0" < filelist | xargs -0 -J {} cp {} fruit`.

Answer (score 0):

Simulate `print0` of find :

`cat filelist |perl -p -e 's/\n/\000/' |xargs -0 cp --target-directory dest_dir/`

this sample includes `xargs -0`,`--target-directory`